# Using MySQL Workbench 8 on RHEL7 gui - When I highlight text in the SQL editor it turns black

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, redhat

I'm assuming this is a config issue in MySQL Workbench or in RHEL. [image]
How can I change this to a readable color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug resolved by upgrading to 8.0.16